# unregister and remove addon in blender with python does not remove the item from menu

Tags: python, export, blender, add-on

I have download some mesh exporter script to learn how to write an export script in python for blender(2.6.3).

The script follows the standard register/unregister in order to register or unregister the script.

```
### REGISTER ###

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(Export_objc.bl_idname, text="Objective-C Header (.h)")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.remove(menu_func)

###if __name__ == "__main__":
### register()
unregister()
```

The issue is that when I use runScript to run the script from the text editor(after changing it to unregister upon run) it removes the the script but leaves an unclickbale leftover in the export menu which I cannot remove.
If I run the register again, it will turn back the inactive menu option into a clickable exporter menu item but in addition it will add another copy of the menu item.
The reason I want to keep registering and unregistering is mostly because I want to make changes and test them out...
Maybe I should run the function directly without registering but even though now I have this in my export menu:

[image]

How do I remove these items and not have many versions of my script in the export menu(depending if I made changes), also should I just put the function instead of the register/unregister when I am fiddling with the script and trying thigns out?

Answer (score 4):

Well I have found a workable way...

If you press 'F8' it will reload all plugins and remove the "dead" menu items.
That solves the multiple additions of the same addon.

So now if I want to change the addon and test it I do something like this:

1. Run script with unregister
2. Press F8
3. Run script with register

That is how I update the addon and there is the additional step of actually running it from the export/import menu.

If you have an easier way to test changes for the addon please let me know...

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% certain of the cause but it relates to running an addon script that adds a menu item within blender's text editor. Even blender's template scripts do the same thing.

I think the best solution is to use it like a real addon - that is save it to disk and enable/disable it in the addon preferences. You can either save it to the installed addons folder, within your [user settings folder](http://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/installing_blender/directorylayout.html) or create a folder and set the [file path for scripts](http://www.blender.org/manual/preferences/file.html#scripts-path). You could also use the [Install from File](http://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/scripting/python/add_ons.html#installation-of-a-3rd-party-add-on) button in the addons preferences.